# Error in Loading image from Firebase Firestore using Glide

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am loading image stored in firebase firestore using Glide. Initially I was loading the image in the same activity where the url link is being fetched from Firebase. Things were running smooth till this point. Now I am trying to load this image in a popUp Activity (basically a different activity). The url is being fetched in the original activity and then being passed on to the popUp Activity.

I have checked that the URL passed to the new activity is correct, however, the same is not loading. Can some one help. The code in the new activity is as follows:

```
val catch = intent.getStringExtra("imgSrc")
popUpText.visibility = View.GONE
if(catch!=null){
                val presImage = PhotoView(this@PopUp)
                val param2: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0F)
                param2.setMargins(0,64,0,0)
                presImage.layoutParams = param2
                presImage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER

                   val popProgress = ProgressBar(this@PopUp)
                    popProgress.layoutParams = param2
                    popProgress.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#beb2bb"))
                    popLayout.addView(popProgress)
                    Glide.with(this@PopUp)
                        .load(Uri.parse(catch))
                        .listener(object: RequestListener<Drawable>{
                            override fun onLoadFailed(
                                e: GlideException?,
                                model: Any?,
                                target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?,
                                isFirstResource: Boolean
                            ): Boolean {
                                return false
                            }

                            override fun onResourceReady(
                                resource: Drawable?,
                                model: Any?,
                                target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?,
                                dataSource: DataSource?,
                                isFirstResource: Boolean
                            ): Boolean {
                                popProgress.visibility=View.GONE
                                return false
                            }

                        })
                        .into(presImage)
}
```

The value of catch is correct. I have checked that by logging the same.
I understand that the error I may be making is likely very trivial, but have spent a lot of time unable to decipher.

Comment: Did you forget add presImage(PhotoView) into  param2(ViewGroup)?

Comment: would that matter? I have loaded photo taken in camera using the same code before uploading that to Firebase. That was a step, which was completed earlier

Comment: ofc its a matter. If you do not show full of code then i dont know where do u wrong at?. So for these above codes. i see wrong when you define programmatically a view and you did not add into parentView. So it can be showed on view although u loaded image.

Comment: oh ... I did not understand your question properly. Yes it should be there and it was there in other part of the code. But the same was not getting accessed because of an error in the rest of the code. I have corrected that. Thanks for pointing that out. Please provide your answer I will accept that.

Comment: so did it show any error message in logcat?. or the code just not work?

Comment: No as you pointed out the View was not properly added to the parent. So it was simply not showing up. A silly error that took 4 hours.

Comment: ah ok. i will post my answer for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls add your child view into parent view to show up on screen.

in that part of code above. you just loaded image into imageView but forgot add imageView into parent View.

Hope this help.